# Break MD5 with partial control of hashed value

Tags: md5

During a pentest some time ago, I came across an interesting functionality, and upon research, it appeared that I had partial control over the starting value in an MD5 hash.

With some more digging, the final hash was a result of `md5(secret-key:my-value)`.

After I realised this, I moved on as the implementation didn't seem vulnerable.

Thinking back, is it possible that this is insecure? For example, it might be brute-forceable with a short secret key. I can't really think of anything else - would be grateful for another point of view.

Comment: I think you are just seeing the law of averages at work.  For any hash function, with a little brute force (~256 attempts), you can find an input that results in a hash where the first byte is 0.  With a little more brute force (~65536 attempts), you can find an input that results in a hash where the first two bytes are 00. etc.  But, this does not necessarily imply that the hash function is week (although MD5 is no longer recommended).

Comment: This is so-called secret prefix construction and is [vulnerable to length extension attacks](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/76960/18298) We have already dupe on the [cryptography.se]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it appeared that I had partial control over the starting value"?

Comment: You say you have partial control over the prefix, but then you give an example where you only have control over the suffix.